# ¿Por que no me funciona el evento onmouseover y onmouseout? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos

en el html cree un div y dentro de el hay un parrafo , al poner el mouse sobre la caja deberia aparecer un texto y al sacar el mouse nada, intente hacerlo asi pero no me funciona:

```js
function validaciones() {
    
    agregarTexto();
    borrarTexto();
}



function agregarTexto() {
    var texto = document.getElementById("texto");

    texto.addEventListener("mouseover" , function(){
        var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
        texto.innerHTML="Hola mundo";
    },false); //intente ponerle como parametro true para que comience este primero pero no fuciona

    
}

function borrarTexto(){

    var texto = document.getElementById("texto");

    texto.addEventListener("mouseout" , function(){
        var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
        texto.innerHTML=" ";
    },false);




    
}

window.addEventListener("load", validaciones,false);
```

```css
#caja{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: black 1px solid;
    width:500px;
    height: 200px; }


#texto{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="caja">

        <p id="texto"></p>
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

tambien intente borrar el parametro false del addEventListener, pero sigue sin funcionar. Y en la consola no me sale ningun error, no se que puede ser :(!

Comment: Carga el script en la parte de abajo, en el cierre del body,                                  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>       </body>

Comment: Tu codigo funciona, agrega texto al parrafo para que veas.

Comment: muchas gracias las dos respuestas son correctas ya funciona :D